# column conditional formatting based on its sum

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have column F2:F23. I want the background of that entire column (`F2:F23`) to either turn red or stay neutral based on whether the sum of the column is greater than the number at cell C2. I tried conditional formatting but it's not working.

```
=Sum(F2:F23)>C2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The answer is this:

```
=Sum($F$2:$F$23)>$C$2
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Conditional formatting** rule should be ***Greater than*** `=$C$2`

Like this:
[image]

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: @MwenRele, please share a sample sheet with what you tried and I'll take a look at it

Comment: all you have to do is open a Sheet. in cell C2 write the number 200 and then choose another column to test the conditional formula against. That's all you need to test this.

Comment: I did that and it workee, therefore I was asking for a sample from you to see what you were missing

Comment: @MwenRele see here a short screen recording https://videobin.org/+177k/1d9x.html

Comment: Upload not working, see it here https://www.sendspace.com/file/re0ay0